# mainloop prevents Tkinter application to run from the IDLE

Tags: python, tkinter

When using Ubuntu, I am able to play with `Tk` in real-time, by writing commands in the `IDLE`.

On Windows, I need to call `root.mainloop()` to spawn a window, and the loop keeps me from running any code from `IDLE`.

Is it a matter of platform, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Whatever may have been true in 2011 about IDLE and Windows is not true now.  I routinely play with tkinter interactively from IDLE by not adding `mainloop()`.  `>>>import tkinter as tk; root = tk.Tk()` spawns a blank tk window.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete solution or answer, but here is something that I found on the subject:

From this page: [Thinking in Tkinter](http://thinkingtkinter.sourceforge.net)

> Note that you should not run these programs under IDLE.   IDLE is itself a Tkinter application, with its own "mainloop" that will conflict with the mainloop in these programs. If you really want to view and run these programs using IDLE, then -- for each program -- you should comment out the "mainloop" statement in the program before running it.

I'm not too sure about the technical reasons behind it -- but I just don't run Tkinter code from IDLE.

Comment: I got a solution: you can preview the app window by defining all geometry and calling update() on the main window. And thanks for the insight, I'll keep that in mind from now on. :)

Comment: "Don't run Tkinter code from IDLE" was obsolete before 2011.  That book was revised in 2009 and written some time before that.  For years, IDLE had run user code in a separate windowless process (unless started with -n) that does not have a tkinter mainloop running.